# Is there an easy way for a python script to bind to all ports on an IP address?

Tags: python, sockets, bind

I'm writing a Python script which connects to remote hosts over a (super complicated) SOCKS/SSL tunnel. I am able to establish connections to IPs in a remote intranet on any port.

What I'm hoping to do is set up this python script to use IP addresses in the local loopback range (127.0.x.x) to become (maybe with the help of the hosts file) a 'replica' of the remote systems, and hence enable me to use applications which don't support proxies. The problem is that I don't always know what ports they're trying to connect to. It seems the only way to work this out is to bind sockets to all 65536 ports, which seems a little crazy. So two questions:

1. Is it crazy? Can I just set up a python list of sockets from 1-65536?
2. Or is there a better way I should be doing this? Can I monitor connections to an IP somehow and bind the ports just before they're needed?

I want to avoid using too much platform-dependent or non-python code if possible.

EDIT: To clarify, I'm only writing the client here - I have no control over the server. Believe me, if I had control over the server side of it I would *not* be doing it with SOCKS/SSL/CRAM :)

Comment: If you're running Linux, I'm pretty sure you could set up `iptables` to do the forwarding for you, and this would have a lot better performance than a Python script that forwards traffic.

Comment: I don't think binding all ports is a good idea, which introduces too much resource overhead.

Comment: Yes, it is crazy. Why not a simple SOCKS/SSL VPN instead of a super complicated SOCKS/SSL tunnel? Smells of unauthorized firewall piercing...

Comment: OK, question 1 answered, it would be crazy :)

Comment: @PauloScardine It's a corporate proxy, based on an Aventail server which uses two nested SOCKS proxies with SSL/CRAM authentication - all above board, just super complicated...

Comment: @kindall I'm unfortunately on windows - I would have been all over iptables if I was in unix :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about going lower level and interfacing a library designed for network analyzers like [pycap](http://pycap.sourceforge.net/)?

This way you could detect all connection attempts and find the ports that you need to expose or may be you can just route the packets directly assuming the library in addition to packet detection can also do packet injection (pypcap page says this feature is experimental).

This would IMO make sense in python only for slow applications however...

Pycap seems to be developed for linux, but the core capturing is done by libpcap and for windows there is a similar library [winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org/).

Comment: I was quietly hoping to avoid using packet capturing within my code :) I'm already making pretty extensive use of Wireshark to look inside the SOCKS data so I'll take a look at what pycap and Wireshark can do for the loopback adapter and see if I can narrow down the number of ports I need to bind.

Answer (score 1):

Matt,

If using windows your best shot is something like OpenVPN over the tunnel. OpenVPN requires only one TCP port/stream and gives you a pair of virtual interfaces with full connectivity.

[updated]

It may be possible using a [TUN/TAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP) driver on the client side. See [this](http://www.secdev.org/projects/tuntap_udp/files/tunproxy.py) unix version for ideas.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not quite what I'm after - I can only write the client. I've updated the question to make that clear.

Comment: I was looking into TUN/TAP for getting some IPs I could bind to, before I realised that the loopback adapter had a whole range (I previously thought it was just 127.0.0.1). I don't want to need to install drivers to get my code to work, but I'll look into it (as with pycap below) and see if it can tell me anything about which ports some of the applications use.